# Error attaching subnets to VPC endpoint AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, vpc, vpc-endpoint

I'm getting an error when I attach subnets to a VPC Endpoint. I have a shared VPC called VCP1 and I need to create a VPC Endpoint with this VPC.
If I don't attach any subnet, the VPC Endpoint are created well, but if I try to attach any subnet of the VPC, I get this error:

```
You are not authorized to perform CreateNetworkInterface operation. A subnet in this vpc is shared but the provided object is not owned by you
```

I'm logged in with admin privileges, and the shared VPC and VPC Endpoint are in the same account and region.

Edit:
My user has attached this policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "*",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: It's maybe your **IAM** (Identity and Access Management) user doesn't have necessary permissions.

Comment: I have edited the post with my user's policy

Comment: Here is what I suspect is going on. The policy you've shown relates to AWS resources in the participant account but not to the VPC-owning account. Participants cannot view, modify, or delete resources that belong to the VPC owner (or other participants).

Comment: Still it seems their is an issue relate to right permission ! It's better to checkout  **AWS** documentation for fix and give right permission.